# What is this miniature? 40K tyranid?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tyranids

Not sure what this is? Thought is was a tyranid but went through the visual archive and could not find it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That looks to be a Tyranid Hierodule bio-titan from Epic 40k, from around 1995.

They were released with the hierophant, but never did as well.

[image: Epic 40k Tyranid hierodule bio-titan]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! I forgot I had a ton of Epic that included some of these. never would have figured it out!

Comment: @ScottGurman, if this answers your question please make sure to select the tick on the left to mark the question as answered